# Stop the Issue Navigator showing up after every run

Tags: xcode

Something changed in Xcode and now every time I run my app it switches tabs to the Issue Navigator automatically. See pic below. How can I stop this from happening?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On the top menu, go to Xcode / Settings / Behaviors. Then uncheck the option pictured below.

[image]

Comment: Unable to keep window still